# Wordpress plugin makes website error: crayon-syntax-highlighter

Tags: wordpress

When I enable the plug-in "crayon-syntax-highlighter" version 2.8.4, my website shows nothing in each page.

---Error message:----

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function id() on array in 
/var/www/it/wp-content/plugins/
crayon-syntax-highlighter/crayon_formatter.class.php:36
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify this file : crayon_langs.class.php

File location: /wp-content/plugins/crayon-syntax-highlighter/crayon_langs.class.php

Going to line# 340

[Before]

```
return preg_replace('/[^\w-+#]/msi', '', $id);
```

Need to add a '' behind w

[After]

```
return preg_replace('/[^\w\-+#]/msi', '', $id);
```

refer to https://crunchify.com/fix-for-crayon-syntax-highlighter-wordpress-plugin-and-php-7-3-fatal-error